# Right click on table name and select design gives unspecified error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

On click of `table name` and `select design` gives me an error saying alert  `"Unspecified error"`. Design mode is not opening at all. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: This usually happens when SQL Server version is later than the version of management studio installed.

Comment: I'm using SQL server management studio  2012 and the version we are usingboth versions same. When i use the same SSMS in another PC/Machine it was working fine. I can see the design mode.

Comment: Has the table been deleted?  SSMS does not automatically update the tables listed in the object explorer (the list is updated the first time you expand it, during a session).  To manually refresh, right click on tables then choose refresh from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SSMS. Check for updates online. I have seen similarly weird behavior in that program lately.

Comment: Same SSMS 2012 in another machine/PC, I can able to open the same table in design mode. But in my PC, It was giving some error. Seems like some settings in SSMS.

Comment: @Hari_Hk I agree. SSMS installs a boatload of stuff, perhaps another app overwrote a DLL or something else that you needed.